Ignore NaN to calculate mean_absolute_error
I'm trying to calculate MAE (Mean absolute error).
In my original DataFrame, I have 1826 rows and 3 columns. I'm using columns 2 and 3 to calculate MAE.
But, in column 2, I have some NaN values.
When I used:
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

and selected these columns, it gave me an error: "Input contains NaN'.
As an example, I'm trying to do something like this:
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7, 10]
y_pred = [2.5, np.NaN, 2, 8, np.NaN]
mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)

Is it possible to skip or ignore the rows with NaN?
UPDATE
I was analyzing with my advisor teacher, and we decided that the best is to drop all these NaN values.

Can't you just drop NaN's? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

I can't do it. The first column represents date, and columns 2 and 3 have specific values for each date.

you can just fill the NaN with any value using fillna()

If I use fillna, it'll change the MAE value

If you can't drop NaNs, you can try to interpolate them. However, you should be careful in terms of the implementation method - if you have multiple NaNs it can impact the MAE signifficantly.

I'm analyzing the same pollutant from two different points: one is being detected in ground and the other is being detected in the atmosphere (by a satellite). And this is why I'm avoiding to drop the values.

@yellow_dot my advisor said that isn't good to interpolate the values

Do you have NaNs in predictions or observations? If in prediction (like you've written), what causes the missing values there?

np.nanmean(abs(y_pred - y_true))

All the values are daily observations, from 2015 to 2019.

If you want to ignore the NaNs, build a mask a perform boolean indexing:
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([3, -0.5, 2, 7, 10])
y_pred = np.array([2.5, np.NaN, 2, 8, np.NaN])
m = ~np.isnan(y_pred)

mean_absolute_error(y_true[m], y_pred[m])

Output: 0.5
